# Quotas Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a simple question, but I feel confused. The [current Google Apps Script's quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) applies per user or per domain or per script file.

For example: The table shows "Feature: Contacts created" - "Google Apps for Work/Edu/Gov:2000/day"... What means?

2000 contacts/day/user? or 2000 contacts/day/domain? or 2000 contacts/day/script?

I test it with a code but it's strange. I can create more than 2000 contacts per user and other day the quota for the same user was over.

Greetings,

Comment: This isn't a programming problem, and as such, it's off-topic here. If you're really concerned, you could raise an issue on the [Google Apps Script Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=quota&colspec=Stars+Opened+ID+Type+Status+Summary+Component+Owner&cells=tiles).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be about Google's policies, and is best asked within their support structure.

Comment: OK, thanks.  I will raise the issue Mogsdad